# Searching MongoDB for records where one date is older than the other

Tags: mongodb, perl, mongodb-query

I have the following example record in MongoDB.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "REDACTED"
  },
  "created": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1671723637000"
    }
  },
  "priority": "1.0",
  "dupdated": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1671727613000"
    }
  },
  "lastmod": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1671758097000"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to return all records where "dupdated" is less than "lastmod" in the database. I am using perl.

Here is the code that worked for "$gt" but it times out for "$lt"

```
my $object;
$object->{'$expr'}->{'$lt'}[0] = '$dupdated'; # Field you want to query against.
$object->{'$expr'}->{'$lt'}[1] = '$lastmod';
my $json = to_json($object);
my @datas = $property->find($object, {projection => {data => 0}})->sort({'dupdated' => 1})->limit(1000)->all();
```

I have 2 indexes.
Index 1

```
dupdated_1_lastmod_1
DUPDATED
LASTMOD
REGULAR
20.9 MB
COMPOUND
```

Index 2

```
dupdated_-1_lastmod_-1
DUPDATED
LASTMOD
REGULAR
11.2 MB
COMPOUND
```

I can't seem to get the dupdated lt lastmod working quickly for some reason. Any insight appreciated.

I tried the code explained above along with the 2 compound indexes. Again, GT works but LT does not.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following demo code sample which based on assumption how data can look.

Your code is not complete to demonstrate the issue, the data sample does not provide enough data for a test.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my @match;

my $json = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $data = from_json($json);

for( $data->@* ) {
    push @match,$_
        if $_->{'dupdated'}{'$date'}{'$numberLong'} < $_->{'lastmod'}{'$date'}{'$numberLong'};
}

say Dumper(\@match);

exit 0;

__DATA__
[
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "NOTREDACTED"
      },
      "created": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1671723637000"
        }
      },
      "priority": "1.0",
      "dupdated": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1671727613000"
        }
      },
      "lastmod": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1671727613000"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "REDACTED"
      },
      "created": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1671723637000"
        }
      },
      "priority": "1.0",
      "dupdated": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1671727613000"
        }
      },
      "lastmod": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1671758097000"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "NOTREDACTED"
      },
      "created": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1671723637000"
        }
      },
      "priority": "1.0",
      "dupdated": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1671727613000"
        }
      },
      "lastmod": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1671727613000"
        }
      }
    }
]
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'lastmod' => {
                           '$date' => {
                                        '$numberLong' => '1671758097000'
                                      }
                         },
            'dupdated' => {
                            '$date' => {
                                         '$numberLong' => '1671727613000'
                                       }
                          },
            '_id' => {
                       '$oid' => 'REDACTED'
                     },
            'created' => {
                           '$date' => {
                                        '$numberLong' => '1671723637000'
                                      }
                         },
            'priority' => '1.0'
          }
        ];
```